# Making winform switch tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, tabs

I'm making a winform in C# using Visual Studio 2008.

Currently, I have a tabcontrol, containing 2 tabs.
In the first the, there is a button. When I click it, I must be taken to the second tab.

Problem is, I don't know how. I've tried debugging, looking into al kinds of Properties and messing around with them, but I found nothing that helps.

Does anybody here know how to pull this off?

Extra info: my variables are named tabControl1, textTab and logTab.

I'm in textTab, click on a button there and I want to be taken to logTab. That's it basically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = logTab;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set either the SelectedIndex property or the SelectedTab property of the tab control to switch tabs.

Comment: I would suggest `SelectIndex` as that is an integer.